# Need A Good Example for Displaytag export with grouping column

Tags: export, decorator, displaytag

I want a good example which show the use of decorator to export reports with displaytag.
I viewed the example provided by displaytag titled "What You See Is What You Get" Exports" 
but onclick of "showcode", it doesn't show its source code.

I am new to displaytag and want to export reports as they see in html.

Answer (score 1):

Look at these links

http://www.displaytag.org/10/export.html

and this tutorial with source code:

http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-display-tag-example-1.html

Comment: Thanks for your Reply.Actually i have no idea how to write a decorator, which can group data as group in html render of listing.Like they did in [link](http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.2/example-new-export.jsp)